# Is there a way to prematurely stop a push notification sound when another push arrives?

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario is i have 29 sec custom audio sound which is like a ringer.

So my scenario is like
push 1 arrives which is a 29 secs ringer 
and continuous ringer starts

but when second push arrives i want this 29 ringer to stop and play the next push sound.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found a solution or a workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to stop the sound of one push notifications if user has enabled it from its global settings of iPhone.

Comment: what i want is not to stop one specific notification sound.. I don't want first push notification sound to overlap with second push notification sound.. Its like when second push arrives first push notification sound should cease..

Comment: Even that too is taken care by the os only. It is also not possible